# How to stop systemd-logind and not be activated later?

Tags: systemd

I want to know how to stop systemd-logind and not be restart or activated later ?

I know that systemd service unit file have a parameter: restart= ,when set its value is no or on-failure, stop this service  like `systemctl stop xxx` ,and this service will not be restart or activated

but systemd-logind looks specical? I am a little puzzled

```
I #systemctl cat systemd-logind
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Login Service
Documentation=man:systemd-logind.service(8) man:logind.conf(5)
Documentation=http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind
Documentation=http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
Wants=user.slice
After=nss-user-lookup.target user.slice

# Ask for the dbus socket. If running over kdbus, the socket will
# not be actually used.
Wants=dbus.socket
After=dbus.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
Restart=no
RestartSec=0
#BusName=org.freedesktop.login1
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYS_ADMIN CAP_MAC_ADMIN CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL CAP_CHOWN CAP_KILL CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_FOWNER CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG
WatchdogSec=1min

# Increase the default a bit in order to allow many simultaneous
# logins since we keep one fd open per session.
LimitNOFILE=16384
```

Comment: Excellent! This was an error I was getting with my lxc, presumably because it used the login from the parent kernel. Disabling this made my container logins MUCH faster.

Answer (score 7):

To stop a service being activated, the right command to use is `systemctl mask ...`.  This will also prevent it being started at boot time.

If you only want to prevent it being started at the moment, use `systemctl mask --runtime`.  This means the setting will be forgotten when you shut down or reboot.

logind is quite important, I would anticipate breaking boot or login - have a rescue disk handy and know how to use it :).

Comment: Thanks a lot, My problem is that systemd-logind running in docker container and restart every minutes, and looks like this problem:https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1961  this phenomenon only occured at docker container , So ,I am trying to stop systemd-logind and I think systemd-logind  is not import in contianer ,What do you think about it ?

Comment: I reallly curious that what is systemd-logind's effect?  when I `systemctl mask systemd-logind ` ,I looks normal, and I can ssh my host normally

Answer (score 3):

To disable [systemd-logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html) you have to mask the service and disable the systemd PAM module (`pam_systemd`). You can do it with the following commands:

`systemctl mask systemd-logind.service
pam-auth-update`

It is reasonably safe and I have done it for many years.

Comment: One caveat is that restarting ssh will then kill all active ssh sessions.  ssh is deliberately designed to avoid that, it's useful e.g. during upgrades.

Comment: you don't need to restart ssh after disabling this "useful" systemd component.

Comment: After I did this in Debian 10, X11 did not start any more.